# Method not calculating the output in the demo class

Tags: java

The first parent class (RoomDimension) is to return a method with the area of a room, the second parent class (RoomCarpet) is to return the total cost of carpeting the said room by gettin the area from the RoomDimension class and multiplying the cost per sq ft in a method in the RoomCarpet class, the demo class is calculating the area but not the final cost of carpeting which is area*cost. Here are the two parent classes and the demo class:

```java
//ROOM DIMENSION CLASS

public class RoomDimension {
    
    private double length;
    private double width;
    
    public RoomDimension(){}
    
    public RoomDimension (double length, double width){
        super();
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }
    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setLength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
    
    public double getFloorArea(){
        return (length * width);
    }
}

////ROOM CARPET CLASS

public class RoomCarpet {
    
    private double carpetCost;
    RoomDimension roomDimension = new RoomDimension();
    
    public RoomCarpet(){}
    
    public RoomCarpet (double carpetCost){
        super();
        this.carpetCost = carpetCost;
    }
    
    public double getCarpetCost(){
        return carpetCost;
    }
    public void setCarpetCost(double carpetCost){
        this.carpetCost = carpetCost;
    }
    
    public double getCarpetingCost(){
        return roomDimension.getFloorArea() * carpetCost;
    }
}

//DEMO CLASS

import java.util.*;

public class CarpetCostDemo {
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        
        double length=0, width=0, carpetCost=0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        RoomDimension roomDimension1 = new RoomDimension();
        RoomCarpet roomCarpet = new RoomCarpet();
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the length of the carpet: ");
        length = input.nextDouble();roomDimension1.setLength(length);
        System.out.println("Please enter the width of the carpet: ");
        width = input.nextDouble();roomDimension1.setWidth(width);
        System.out.println("Please enter the cost per sq ft of the carpet: ");
        carpetCost = input.nextDouble();roomCarpet.setCarpetCost(carpetCost);
        
        System.out.println("The cost to carpet your room with an area of " 
       +roomDimension1.getFloorArea()+" sq ft is: $"+roomCarpet.getCarpetingCost());    
    }
}
```

The total cost is printing as zero in the console.

Comment: You don't pass the `RoomDimension` into your `RoomCarpet`. Your `getCarpetingCost()` method just uses an internal `RoomDimension` which is unrelated to the one you're passing the inputs to.

Comment: So Tim, creating an object of RoomDimension in the RoomCarpet class does not do that? I thought that was the purpose of creating an instance of that class in the second class? I thought about that and so tried changing the RoomCarpet object name in the demo class and tried passing inputs to both the instances of the two classes but that did not help.

Comment: Your `RoomCarpet` will only look at the values you assign to the `RoomDimension` stored internally in it's current form. You need to either replace that internal `RoomDimension` with the one you create and populate in your `main` method or directly update the values of the internal `RoomDimension`.

Comment: if you want to use a single instance of the `RoomDimension` you need to use something like the singleton pattern

Comment: @Bargros Or just make it all `static`, since it's just a data container essentially. Though if that's the case, they may as well just move the `length` and `width` into the `RoomCarpet` if that's the only place the data is being used anyways.

Comment: @TimHunter Yeah that would also work but I honestly don't see the point in having a static property in a non-static class, think about it, what would be the use of having a class that you can instantiate but the value is shared across all its instances, so if one is modified, they all change. Doesn't seem like a very useful class at all, the singleton pattern implies the same instance will be used and the class itself cannot be instantiated. How the class its used is implied in the code, unlike a class with a static property, is just confusing.

Comment: Tim, I used the same object (roomDimension) in both the Main and in the RoomCarpet class, no go. I have to create two parent classes because that is what the problem in the textbook asks for. Since there is an object of RoomDimension created in the RoomCarpet class should it not take the claculated value of Area from the RoomDimension class and then multiply it with the value of the carpetCost that is being passed to the RoomDimension method?

Comment: Bargros, I tried reading up about the singleton pattern, I don't think I have enough JAVA knowledge yet to understand or implement that here. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RoomDimension {

private double length;
private double width;

public RoomDimension(){}

public RoomDimension (double length, double width){
   // super();
   //you don't need super since you are not
   // extending any class            
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}
public double getLength() {
    return length;
}
public double getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setLength(double length) {
    this.length = length;
}
public void setWidth(double width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public double getFloorArea(){
    return (length * width);
}
```

}

////ROOM CARPET CLASS

public class RoomCarpet {

```
private double carpetCost;
private RoomDimension roomDimension ;
```

// you don't have you instantiate the //roomDimension when creating this class,
//provide its value using setter at runtime

```
public RoomCarpet(){}

public RoomCarpet (double carpetCost){
  //  super();
    this.carpetCost = carpetCost;
}

public double getCarpetCost(){
    return carpetCost;
}
public void setCarpetCost(double carpetCost){
    this.carpetCost = carpetCost;
}



  public void setRoomDimension(RoomDimension roomD){
          this.roomDimension = roomD;
   }
    public double getCarpetingCost(){
        return roomDimension.getFloorArea() * carpetCost;
    }
}
```

////DEMO CLASS

import java.util.*;

public class CarpetCostDemo {

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    
    double length=0, width=0, carpetCost=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    RoomDimension roomDimension1 = new RoomDimension();
    RoomCarpet roomCarpet = new RoomCarpet();
    
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of the carpet: ");
    length = input.nextDouble();roomDimension1.setLength(length);
    System.out.println("Please enter the width of the carpet: ");
    width = input.nextDouble();roomDimension1.setWidth(width);
    System.out.println("Please enter the cost per sq ft of the carpet: ");
    carpetCost = input.nextDouble();roomCarpet.setCarpetCost(carpetCost);
roomCarpet.set(roomDimension1);
    System.out.println("The cost to carpet your room with an area of " 
   +roomDimension1.getFloorArea()+" sq ft is: $"+roomCarpet.getCarpetingCost());    
}
```

}

Comment: I got it to work, I passed this roomCarpet.setRoomDimension(roomDimension1); and its working, thanks buddy, appreciate it.

Comment: Hello, your code hasn't worked properly because you didn't supply the roomCarpet object with the reference of roomDimension1 object that you have created in the demo class, for that i added the setter of the roomDiemension object in the RoomCarpet Class. roomCarpet.set(roomDimension1) this will supply the roomCarpet with RommDimension object and your code will work just fine

Comment: sorry roomCarpet.setRoomDimension(roomDimension1) not roomCarpet.set(roomDimension1)